# Loading different properties files into persistence.xml in a maven spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a scenario where I have to load different dialect,provider into my persistence.xml file based upon the environment  I am deploying the application.

For Eg

In one environment I am using Oracle11g and in another I am using MySql8. 
I want my persistnece.xml to look something like this.

```
<persistence-unit name="firstPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>${somekey.provider}</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${somekey.dialect}" />
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Then have two separate property files(first.property, second.property) and select either one of them using build profile in my pom.xml. For Eg-

```
<profile> 
.
.
.
<build> 
            <resources> 
                <resource> 
                    <directory>src/main/resources/config/${build.profile.id}</directory> 
                    <excludes> 
                    <exclude>**/first.properties</exclude> 
                    </excludes> 
                </resource> 
            </resources> 
        </build>
.
.
.
</profile>
```

So based upon the profile selected it will exclude one of the .property files and read from the other.

The issue with all this is the values are returning as null from the property files. (*not anymore*)

Am I missing something here or is there a better way to do this sort of stuff ?

**Update--**

this is working fine for reading dialect values. However, I can't read Provider !!

Is it possible to read Provider value as well from a property file ?

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `persistence.xml` and configure the `LocalEntityManagerFactory` with Spring using placeholders. This way you can simply add a properties file and change the content, without needing to recreate the artifact.

Create an `application.properties` file (or whatever name you like) and add the following

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

Then, assuming you are using java based configuration, add an `@PropertySource` to (optionally) load this file from an **external** location.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/conf/application.properties")
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource ds) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory();
        emf.setDataSource(ds);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapater(jpaVendorAdapter());
        // Other settings
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.database-platform"));
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Now you can change the dialect (and other properties if needed) to anything you like.

**NOTE:** the name of the property was chosen to be the same as the one from Spring Boot, so that you can reuse this configuration when switching to Spring Boot, which supports all of this out-of-the-box.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of defining properties in `persistence.xml`, you can define all these database details in the properties file and in build script you can include respective property file in your war/ear.

```
final Properties persistenceProperties = new Properties();
InputStream is = null;

try {
    is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("persistence.properties");
    persistenceProperties.load(is);
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}

entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("firstPU", persistenceProperties);
```

Refer this [link](https://gerardnico.com/jpa/property) for more details

Comment: The question is how to do this with Spring. You don't need to load your own properties as Spring has out-of-the-box support for this.

Comment: This is working fine for reading dialect info. But the provider is not getting loaded from the property file. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Your persistence provider must be the same . you can initialize it separatly